One-line private comment when downvoting
I got a few downvoted questions, and would love to know why. I think it would be really good if it were possible for downvoters to write even a few words as to why they did so.
This is not because I think they're necessarily wrong, but because I legitimately don't know what's wrong with my question. I HAVE had one closed recently, with a reason, and that is understandable. I think for posts that end up in the negative, it would be helpful for users to have some kind of inkling as to how to improve, both in the way they ask questions but also a nudge as to what questions may just not be appropriate.
As it stands, from someone who doesn't post much, it feels a bit hit-and-miss with the questions, I guess as I'm not exposed to too many flame wars or the likes that cause other users to guard their responses. It's a feels bad situation with a post in the negative with not even a single comment, that just makes it feel like SO is not the place to ask questions. Probably not an issue if you've asked tons and know the scope boundaries.

Related (possible duplicate): Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?

Actually, I think you're right

I honestly don't see anything wrong with your question on SO...  It might potentially be a duplicate, but if that’s the case, it would be marked as such.

"I think it would be really good if it were possible for downvoters to write even a few words as to why they did so." It already is; that's one of the main purposes of the comments section. Many users just don't bother because their feedback is frequently met with abuse, denial, or unwarranted accusations of being "unfriendly" or "toxic".

Fair enough. By the way, THIS post is now in the negative. I suppose I just need to get used to it

In this instance I expect the downvotes are for a lack of research effort, as this is a topic that's been posted about ad infinitum ad nauseum here on MSE. This is actually one of the most polite and reasonable questions I've seen on the topic.

Makes sense. I appricate the feedback

If I look at that question, you got feedback by 3 users one of which might have cast a downvote. You're well served? Given you have enough reputation, you can try chat for more criticism but be aware of the meta effect
